# How to add a checkbox in a alert panel?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I want to add a checkbox in a alert panel . But now I found that the func: setShowsSuppressionButton not be used under MAX 10.5. My system version is 10.4.11 ! Which other methods I can do ? I didn't
want to make a panel by my self . Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to create your own NSPanel and show it modally instead of using NSAlert. NSAlert's accessory view and suppression button properties didn't exist prior to Leopard.

Answer (score 0):

You could alternatively just build a custom view that functions similarly to the way an actual NSAlert/NSPanel functions -perhaps even better for your specific needs.